# Label Text is Limited

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this to change the text of label

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
}
```

But the label only show `The quick brown fox` not the whole.

Comment: try setting this in your form constructor `label1.AutoSize = true;`?

Comment: I tried it but did not work

Comment: Could you show the screen shot? (post the link to the screen shot). Where do you add the line I suggested?

Comment: Where is your label positioned? If auto size didn't work then either another control is overlapping the text or its going out of the windows area

Answer (score 1):

Either make your label control larger to fit the entire text, or set `AutoSize` property to `True` to let it automatically adjust to the content size. Also make sure there's no other control hiding part of your label.

Comment: Making label control larger works. It's weird that Autosize propert to True don't works.

Comment: @BagsBanny what kind of `Label` are you using? Is it the standard label?

Comment: Also check if you have any other property of the label that is not on its default value. Specifically, `Anchor` can cause this. There may be some more.

Answer (score 0):

Based on King King *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041987/label-text-is-limited#comment26394493_18041987)*, looks like your label doesn't show entire text because of its size.

Try to set [`Label.AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true`.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control is **automatically
>   resized to display its entire contents.**

```
label1.AutoSize = true;
```